# Matlab - Plotting filtered audio

Tags: matlab, audio, fft, transformation

I'm trying to plot a filtered audio, but I'm doing something wrong because the second plot shows nothing.

```
[wave,fs]=wavread('my-audio.wav');
t=0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs;
figure(1);plot(t,wave);
b = [1.1 1];
a = [-0.1 0 1];
FIR = filter(b,a,wave);
figure(2);plot(t,FIR);
```

The function I'm using is: `H(z)=(z + 1.1)/(z^2 - 0.1)`

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've inverted the order of the coefficients in the `a` and `b` vectors. Inverting the order of coefficients is particularly dramatic for the feedback coefficients `a` which define the poles of the transfer function (and hence determine the stability of the filter). The resulting filtered output `FIR` thus likely exceeds numerical float capacity, which `plot` has trouble with.

According to [`filter`'s documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html), the `a` and `b` coefficients are defined using a [transfer function of the form](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#buagwwg-2):

[image: H(z) = \frac{b(1) + b(2)z^{-1} + \dots + b(n)z^{-n}}{a(1) + a(2)z^{-1} + \dots + a(m)z^{-m}}]

Since your transfer function is

[image: \begin{align}H(z) &= \frac{z + 1.1}{z^2 - 0.1} \ &= \frac{z^{-1} + 1.1z^{-2}}{1 - 0.1z^{-2}}\end{align}]

you should be using the coefficients

```
b = [0  1  1.1]
a = [1  0 -0.1]
```